# How to convert rails3 routes into rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have following rails3 routes that I want to convert into rails4.

```
map.with_options(:conditions => {:subdomain => AppConfig['admin_subdomain']}) do |subdom|
  subdom.root :controller => 'subscription_admin/subscriptions', :action => 'index'
  subdom.with_options(:namespace => 'subscription_admin/', :name_prefix => 'admin_', :path_prefix => nil) do |admin|
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace :admin do
  constraints subdomain: AppConfig['admin_subdomain'] do
    root to: 'subscription_admin/subscriptions#index'
    namespace :subscription_admin do
      resources :some_resources
        # RESTful routes
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[More info about constrains](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints).

Comment: constraints subdomain: AppConfig['admin_subdomain']